# .htaccess file causing 404

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, rest

I have an .htaccess file in my public_html folder which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !"/ntransfers/" 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

in /ntransfers/ there is a subdirectory, /admin/. In this sub-directory there is another .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/devsend/public_html/ntransfers/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

My goal is to ignore /ntransfers/ and all of its sub-directories when it comes to the rewrite rule...

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

...which I am using to do routing with slimPHP.

I have tried changing the directory in my RewriteCond, as well as putting RewriteEngine Off lines in various .htaccess files located at different sub-directory levels.

Is there anything I can do to completely ignore a directory and all of its sub-directories for a RewriteRule?

EDIT

I have updated my .htaccess to the following and stil no luck:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ntransfers$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ntransfers/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

EDIT 2

If I alter my sub-directory .htaccess file in the following way it works...

```
Options -Indexes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/devsend/public_html/ntransfers/admin/.htpasswd
#Require valid-user
```

...however this disables authentication.

EDIT 3

With all the changes, this is what what both .htaccess files look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ntransfers$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ntransfers/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And in the sub-directory:

```
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch ".">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/devsend/public_html/ntransfers/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

The directory structure:

```
/www
    .htaccess
    /ntransfers
        /admin
            .htacess
```

Comment: Do you even have `index.php` inside `/home/devsend/public_html/ntransfers/admin/`?

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it,

change

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !"/ntransfers/"`

to

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ntransfers/`

edit: missed the subdirectories bit, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ntransfers$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ntransfers/.*
```

Comment: Tried and still no luck.

/public_html/___ works fine  


/public_html/ntransfers/ works fine  


/public_html/ntransfers/admin/ throws 404

Comment: Still no luck! If I disable the user authentication part in the sub-directory .htaccess file, it works fine, specifically the line Require valid-user

Comment: Ahh... auth runs first, it's conflicting. I suspect if you check your logs it's actually looking for the 401 (auth needed) page. quick hack, surround your auth section with <FilesMatch "."> ... </FilesMatch>

Comment: Still nothing, it is going to a 404 page.

Comment: Weird. Could you take a look at my edit? I have a feeling it's probably something dumb I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Many years late, but if you folder structure is correct, you spelt htaccess incorrectly in the subfolder :P